# Авторизация ВК через Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, chromedriver

Делаю парсер для вк и наткнулся на проблему с авторизацией, т.е `selenium` выдаёт:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: "element not interactable"
```

Код:

```
    program.driver.Url = ("https://vk.com/");
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(@"form#index_login_form > input#index_email:nth-child(7)")));
    Console.WriteLine("Сайт VK загружен");

    program.driver.FindElement(By.Name(@"email")).SendKeys(phone_number);
```

Думал, что страница до конца не загружается, но нет. Что делать?

Comment: у VK разве нет своего API? В чеми смысл парсера под VK?

Comment: Есть. Смысла нет, но хочется попробовать.

Comment: вероятнее всего страница не прогрузилась полностью или же ты обращаешся не к тому элементу. Потому что он "not interactable" - советую обратить внимение на совет с API